# limpiar un select en jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Al hacer una consulta por medio de ajax, de los parametros que estoy enviando son enviados por selects pero el problema es que una vez realizada la consulta los values permanecen ahi y no me quieren borrar, he utilizado la opcion `empty()` pero cuando lo hago me borran los option y yo no quiero eso, me podian ayudar en esto por favor, les dejo el codigo html y javascript

```
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <select name="" id="select_granjas" class="form-control">
                        <option value="" selected="selected">Seleccione Granja: </option>
                        @foreach($granjas as $granja)
                            <option value="{{$granja->id}}">{{$granja->nombre_granja}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>
```

ese foreach es por medio de laravel, pero solo necesito que en javascript me limpie ese select pero que no me borre los datos que hay adentro.

```
var array_granjas = [];
$('#select_granjas').on('change', function(e){
        array_granjas.push($(e.currentTarget).val())
        console.log('value_select_prueba: --------->', array_granjas);
})
```

en este `array` estoy guardando multiples values de ese select ya aca abajo lo llamo para el ajax

$("#elaborar_grafica_granjas_conversion_final").click(function () {
            var datachart = new Array();
            var token = $("#token").val();
            var a_granjas = $("#select_granjas_conversion_final").val();
            var mes = $("#select_granjas_mes").val();

```
        var json = {
            annio_granjas:a_granjas,
            granjas:array_granjas,
            mes:mes
        }

        console.log(json);

        if (a_granjas == '') {
            swal({
                title:"No hay Fecha seleccionada.",
                text:'',
                type:'warning',
                showCancelButton:false,
                confirmButtonClass:'btn-warning',
                confirmButtonText:'Corregir',
            });
        }else{
            $.ajax({
                method:'POST',
                headers:{'X-CSRF-TOKEN':token},
                url:'http://201.236.212.130:82/intranetcercafe/public/admin/report_destete_finalizacion_conversion_final_granjas',
                data:json
            }).done(function (msg){
                console.log(msg);
                console.log(array_granjas);
                array_granjas.length=0;
            })
        }
    })
```

el array granjas lo que me hace es limpiar el array mas no el select

Comment: quieres dejar el un valor por defecto en el select? , porque no muestra un poco de código que estas haciendo para ayudarte.

Comment: listo ya lo adapte

Answer (score 1):

A mi de ma la impresion de que quieres que funcione tal que así

```js
      var array_granjas = [];
    $('#select_granjas').on('change', function(e){
        array_granjas.push($(e.currentTarget).val())
        console.log('value_select_prueba: --------->', array_granjas);
       $(this).val("");
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
    <select name="" id="select_granjas" class="form-control">
      <option value="" selected="selected">Seleccione Granja: </option>
      <option value="1">Granja 1</option>
      <option value="2">Granja 2</option>
      <option value="3">Granja 3</option>

    </select>
  </div>
```

Prueba adáptalo a tu proyecto.
La única diferencia es esta linea `$(this).val("");` que ingrese en el change del select.Lo que hace esa linea es que el value del select sea `""`, entonces se va al valor del select que tiene eso en este caso el primer option.Espero que te sirva.

Comment: ps si pero yo quiero que el select este vacio visualmente una vez hecho el ajax, me entiendes, yo vacio el array pero que visualmente el select no tenga nada

Comment: entonces le haces `empty()` y luego le pones un append a select asi `$('#select_granjas').append('<option value="" selected="selected">Seleccione Granja: </option>')`

Comment: muchas gracias amigo pero no utiliza el ´empty()´ ya que me elimaba todos los datos asi que solo agregue ´append´

Comment: @JuanEstebanYarce pones la flag como `[resolvido]` en su tópico.